# Knockout.js - Forcing input to be numeric - allow dot and comma notation

Tags: knockout-2.0, knockout-validation

To better understand, pls go to http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html and have a look at Live Example 1: Forcing input to be numeric

I can enter a decimal value with a . (dot) but not with a comma.  Then the amount jumps to 0.

Any idea how I can allow dot AND comma?  I would like to allow input like 20.00 and 20,00

Kind regards,

K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a small fix in the numeric extender (ref. the extenders documentation page that you posted) to solve this. In the "write" method of the extender, add the following code on top:

```
        if (typeof newValue == "string") {
            newValue = newValue.replace(",", ".");
        }
```

The if-statement is needed to prevent an error on model initialization. When the model is first created, the value is most likely set to a number instead of a string, so we can't call the .replace method on this object.

Answer (score 1):

You may not only want to **accept numeric fields** with comma, but also **output numbers from you VM with comma** as decimal point. Thus, you need also to implement `read` getter function of the underlying computed observable. Also `write` function could be simplified if you don't care about rounding. Here is the full code:

```
ko.extenders.numeric = function(target) {
    var result = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            var value = target();
            return isNaN(value) || value===null || value===''
                ? value
                : value.toString().replace('.',',');
        }
        ,write: function(newValue) {
            if (typeof newValue === "string") {
                newValue = newValue.replace(",", ".");
            }
            if (newValue !== target()) {
                target(newValue);
            }
        }
    });
    result(target());
    return result;
};
```